# Redefining "class" keyword in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, syntax

To define a class I must do the following (for example)

```
class Foo
   #attr_accessors
   #methods
   #so on
end
foo = Foo.new #to create an instance
```

## Problem

I need to achieve the following

```
case_class Foo_inmutable #I change class for case_class
   #attr_accessors
   #methods
   #so on
end
foo_inmutable = Foo_inmutable.new 
#->SyntaxError: uninitialze constant Foo_inmutable
```

I need the ruby interpreter to treat the **case_class** the same way to keyword **class**

Comment: Changing the keywords for a language is almost never the best way to go about doing whatever it is you're trying to do. Why do you want to create an alias for class? What is your end goal? This could be an example of [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: You can't arbitrarily redefine the syntax. What's your use case here? Why do you need an alternative to `class`? Does `Class.new` not give you enough control when making arbitrary classes?

Comment: Hamms, I don't trying to change the keyword "class" simply I want extend de Ruby language with somethig similiar to  "class" keyword for academic reasons.

Comment: I just want to take advantage of the metamodel and the concept of open classes that ruby gives us.

Comment: For what its worth I think it IS a relevant question if you are into language design and are using Ruby precisely because of its strong metaprogramming facilities. In fact I had a similar use-case where I wanted to define a new language feature similar to, but not quite the same as, a class, for which I want to redefine / extend the given syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Like almost all programming languages, Ruby does not allow you to modify its syntax or semantics. So, what you want is not possible.

You *can*, however, quite easily write a method that accomplishes your goal, but without changing the syntax and semantics of Ruby:

```
class Module
  def case_class(name, superclass = ::Object, &blk)
    const_set(name, Class.new(superclass, &blk))
  end
end

def case_class(name, superclass = ::Object, &blk)
  self.class.case_class(name, superclass, &blk)
end

case_class :Foo_immutable do
#          ↑              ↑↑
# these are the only differences to your proposed syntax

  #attr_accessors
  #methods
  #so on
end

foo_immutable = Foo_immutable.new
```

Comment: Yes! That is what I needed!  It works perfectly. Thanks Jörg W Mittag

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, besides defining what's already been said in the previous answer:

```
class Module
  def case_class(name, superclass = ::Object, &blk)
    const_set(name, Class.new(superclass, &blk))
  end
end

def case_class(name, superclass = ::Object, &blk)
  self.class.case_class(name, superclass, &blk)
end
```

You may want to have a look at the **const_missing** method, and the "Lookup" that ruby does for constants inside the various scopes

That will allow you to do stuff like

```
case_class Foo do
...
end
```

For further explanation you can refer to this page: [tadp-utn-frba.github.io](http://tadp-utn-frba.github.io)

It has tons of useful scripts explaining ruby metaprogramming (in spanish) and how to achieve what you are looking for, also it has contact references for the
people in charge of the page, so you can email them at any time (Given you are a student of the class) ***for academic reasons***.

Cheers!

Comment: I assume that `const_missing` is similar to `method_missing` and allows you to capture the undefined constant name `Foo` at the moment to define it at that moment instead?