# Case classes in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

Im trying to implement case_class in Ruby for academic reasons.
I have already read this question [Redefining "class" keyword in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268198/redefining-class-keyword-in-ruby)

I'm having troubles to understand why def case_class is used inside a Module. Why are there two definitions of case_class?

The author of the answer says this "foo_immutable = Foo_immutable.new" works,
using the same code and irb I get

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Foo_inmutable
from (irb):3
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Why does that happen? How should I initialize the constant?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, a class is a instance of class Class, and Class inherited Module. For example:

```
class A
end
```

we defined a class A, it's class, so A is a instance of Class.

Since A is a instance of Class, it get all the instance methods in Class. And because Class inherited Module, and Module has this instance method "case_class", so, A get the method "case_class".

we can invoke like this: A.case_class. That why we defined "case_class" method in Module: in order to make all the classes have this method.

Second, these two method do not need to have the same name, the second invoke the first, by self.class.case_class(name, superclass, &blk).

Comment: thanks! your explanation is great